# C# How to copy strings from web response

Tags: c#, string

How can I get and copy to table specified strings from response(I Think that it is same as getting from any text)?

I mean that for example I am getting response like:

PSEUDO CODE:

> "blablabla... rank:1, name:string1, blablabla, rank:2, name:string2... "

I would like to get and copy `string1,string2,string3,...,` to table. How can I do IT?

Comment: Do you really get data in such format from web server? Not JSON, XML or HTML?

Comment: If you are having a problem with your JSON, please do not post *pseudo*-JSON!

Comment: Be more precise with your question, is completely vague, we can't understand if the answer is a json or what. If you want help, you must help us first understanding you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to match the names and get the values in an array.

```
string input = "blablabla... rank:1, name:string1, blablabla, rank:2, name:string2";

string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, @"name:(?<Name>[^,]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(o => o.Groups["Name"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need (I'm not sure, question is not very clever) to parse JSON into a C# collection of some type (if the response is JSON) and then you can access data easily.

To parse JSON, see this question: [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: Can't be JSON: `name:string1` would have to be `name:"string1"`

Comment: He said "pseudocode", quotes can definitely be omitted I think

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result is really not JSON (see my comment to @Fire-Dragon-DoL), I would recommen parsing this with a regex:

- use "name:([^,])" to capture a single string
- Use either the combination IList-ToArray()-Join(",") or a StringBuilder to concatenate